# Не отображается страница Health

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Подключил к проекту эту зависимость.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

В конфиге прописал следующие настройки:

```
endpoints:
    enabled: false
    trace:
      enabled: true
    metrics:
      enabled: true
    health:
      enabled: true
    info:
      enabled: true
```

Перехожу на страницу http://localhost:8080/health. И получаю

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

Вот мой pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
<artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <spring.boot.version>2.0.3.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.3-1101-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Что я сделал не так?

Answer (score 0):

Точки входа находятся под /actuator, например, http://localhost:8080/actuator/health. [Пруф](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints)

Comment: по такому пути тоже 404